# How to search for multiple entries in SQL Query?

Tags: sql

When trying to search for one book title's number of copies in every branch in my Library Database this works great:

```
select BranchName, Title, sum(No_Of_Copies) as NumberOfCopies
    from Library_Branch lb
    join Book_Copies bc
    on lb.BranchId = bc.BranchId
    join BOOK b
    on bc.BookId = b.BookId WHERE Title like '%The Great Gatsby%'
    group by lb.BranchName, b.Title
```

But when I try to search for two books I get an error:

```
select BranchName, Title, sum(No_Of_Copies) as NumberOfCopies
    from Library_Branch lb
    join Book_Copies bc
    on lb.BranchId = bc.BranchId
    join BOOK b
    on bc.BookId = b.BookId WHERE Title like '%The Great Gatsby%' , '%The Chronicles of Narnia'
    group by lb.BranchName, b.Title
```

I have also tried:

```
select BranchName, Title, sum(No_Of_Copies) as NumberOfCopies
    from Library_Branch lb
    join Book_Copies bc
    on lb.BranchId = bc.BranchId
    join BOOK b
    on bc.BookId = b.BookId WHERE Title like '%The Great Gatsby%' or '%The Chronicles of Narnia'
    group by lb.BranchName, b.Title
```

Comment: WHERE title LIKE.. or title LIKE..

Answer (score 1):

You have to totally rewrite the where condition after the OR:

```
select BranchName, Title, sum(No_Of_Copies) as NumberOfCopies
    from Library_Branch lb
    join Book_Copies bc
    on lb.BranchId = bc.BranchId
    join BOOK b
    on bc.BookId = b.BookId WHERE Title like '%The Great Gatsby%' or Title like '%The Chronicles of Narnia'
    group by lb.BranchName, b.Title
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close, try this:

```
SELECT BranchName, Title, sum(No_Of_Copies) as NumberOfCopies
FROM Library_Branch lb
JOIN Book_Copies bc on lb.BranchId = bc.BranchId
JOIN BOOK b on bc.BookId = b.BookId 
WHERE Title LIKE '%The Great Gatsby%' or Title LIKE '%The Chronicles of Narnia'
GROUP BY lb.BranchName, b.Title
```